# IBM Websphere Portal server 8.5 Impersonation

Tags: java, websphere-portal

Getting below error in the logs after successful impersonation.

```
[12/21/16 15:27:03:732 IST] 0000015b ActionRespons E com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.core.impl.ActionResponseImpl setRenderParameter EJPPC0161E: Cannot set RenderParameter after sendRedirect has been called
[12/21/16 15:27:03:732 IST] 0000015b SystemOut     O 2016-12-21 
[12/21/16 15:27:03:733 IST] 0000015b SystemOut     O 2016-12-21 15:27:03.732[WebContainer : 5][ERROR] com.portal.base.FacesPortlet - Can't invoke setRenderParameter() after sendRedirect() has been called
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't invoke setRenderParameter() after sendRedirect() has been called
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.core.impl.ActionResponseImpl.setRenderParameter(ActionResponseImpl.java:109)
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.httpbridge.ActionResponseWrapper.setRenderParameter(ActionResponseWrapper.java:38)
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.encodeObject(FacesPortlet.java:888)
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.saveViewState(FacesPortlet.java:953)
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.saveViewState(FacesPortlet.java:961)
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.processAction(FacesPortlet.java:284)
```

Comment: Post the code about this error

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ibm impersonation portlet and is the full stack coming from there.  if so open a PMR with IBM 
otherwise that is a valid response, you cannot set parameters after issuing a send redirect because portal commits the response and you end up with that error